# implementing two set of filter criteria in quicksand

Tags: jquery, quicksand

I am not so god at debugging Jquery plugins.
In my current project I need to implement the quicksand  plugin.
I have made that working but the problem arises when the data need to be filtered in respect to two set of filtration.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example: http://www.danieltulp.nl/work/quicksand-multiple.htm

And here is the thread where I found it (includes zip of working example).

I had to do the same thing an integrated it on my site.

Answer (score 0):

I have used two filters in my example.

Here you can find it: http://jsfiddle.net/AVnzX/

This is my filter, a combination of filtering and sorting:

```
<form id="filter">
<select name="country" id="filterCountry">
    <option value="alle">Alle</option>
    <option value="usa">USA</option>
    <option value="germany">Germany</option>
    <option value="australia">Australia</option>
</select>
<select name="city" id="filterCity">
    <option value="alle">Alle</option>
    <option value="newyork">New York</option>
    <option value="sydney">Sydney</option>
    <option value="paris">Paris</option>
    <option value="munich">Munich</option>
    <option value="berlin">Berlin</option>
    <option value="losangeles">Los Angeles</option>
    <option value="miami">Miami</option>
    <option value="hamburg">Hamburg</option>
    <option value="frankfurt">Frankfurt</option>
    <option value="sanfrancisco">San Francisco</option>
</select>
<select name="alphabet" id="filterName">
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="country">Country</option>
    <option value="city">City</option>
</select>
```